# How to use the max number of tokens with the openai api?

Tags: openai-api

I want to extract ("parse out") some text from some "unstructured data". So the only robust way I've found to do this is using GPT4. When I try it on ChatGPT (with GPT4) web interface it works -- though because it's a lot of text I do have to click the continuation button. But it works as I wanted.

But when I use it with the openai API I get that it terminates to soon. Which is confusing me. How does one make sure that the max number of tokens for the model are always used?

Extract text

```py
def extract_content_from_with_gpt(
        text_list: str, 
        model_name: str = 'gpt-4-1106-preview', 
        # model_name: str = 'gpt-3.5-turbo', 
        temperature: float = 0.7,
    ) -> list[tuple[int, str]]:
    prompt: str = get_prompt_extract_list_from_text(text_list)
    response = openai.chat.completions.create(
        model = model_name,
        messages = 
        [
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
        ],
        temperature = temperature,
        # max_tokens=128_000,
    )
    response_text: str = response.choices[0].message.content.strip()
    pattern = r"<extracted>(.*?)</extracted>"
    match: list[str] = re.findall(pattern, response_text, re.DOTALL)
    assert len(match) == 1
    # extracted_list: list[str] = eval(match[0])
    extracted_list: list[str] = ast.literal_eval(match[0])
    return extracted_list
```

is this how it's done?

related: https://community.openai.com/t/max-tokens-how-to-get-gpt-to-use-the-maximum-available-tokens/433367

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using gpt-4-1106-preview which is the turbo model. The input and output tokens for gpt-4 turbo are not the same. It has an input token limit(context space) of 128 K but output is limited to 4096 tokens. Although max token is 4096, it does not guarantee that you will always get that many tokens, it will stop when it encounters a stop token.

Comment: how is it that it's output is 4096? the attention mechanism is roughly `[Tx, D_Q] * [ D_K, Tx'] * [Tx', Dv]` which means it's output is always the same as its input. I am assuming this must be wrong. Do you mind clarifying me how this is wrong? Thanks for the help btw!